# Join 2 tables and display duplicated row value into new column

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been spending 2 days working on this and cannot find anything help.

I have 2 tables.

**1. players**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | AA |
| 2 | BB |
| 3 | CC |
| 4 | DD |

**2. matching**

| id | player_id | match_id | date | has_opponent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2021-06-23 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 2021-06-23 | 0 |
| 3 | 3 | 2 | 2021-06-21 | 0 |
| 4 | 4 | 3 | 2021-06-22 | 1 |

**Expected Result**

| match_id | date | first_opponent_name | second_opponent_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-06-23 | AA | BB |
| 2 | 2021-06-21 | CC |  |
| 3 | 2021-06-22 | DD | DD |

I want to join these 2 tables with new columns ( first_opponent_name & second_opponent_name )
if it meets condition as below:

1. If there is a duplicated **match_id**  but it has different **player_id**,  then display their names in 2 separated columns.
2. If there is only 1 **match_id** and it has 1 **player_id** and **has_opponent** column is 0, then this should display only first_opponent_name
3. If there is only 1 **match_id** and it has 1 **player_id** and has_opponent column is 1,  then **first_opponent_name** and **second_opponent** _name should be displayed as the same value.

Comment: What have you tried so far and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Those targeted questions, sounds like a homework?

Comment: I'm trying to create a booking system, Sir!

Answer (score 1):

Not tested but I think this will work, basically it joins the table to itself on the different scenarios and then checks which scenario it's matched.

```
SELECT
  m.match_id
 ,m.date
 ,p1.name AS first_opponent_name
 ,CASE WHEN p2.name IS NOT NULL THEN p2.name 
       WHEN nop2.match_id IS NOT NULL THEN '' 
       WHEN samep2.match_id IS NOT NULL THEN p1.name END AS second_opponent_name 
FROM
  matching AS m
INNER JOIN players AS p1
  ON m.player_id = p1.player_id 
LEFT JOIN matching AS hasp2
  ON m.match_id = hasp2.match_id
  AND m.player_id <> hasp2.player_id
LEFT JOIN players AS p2
  ON hasp2.player_id = p2.player_id
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    match_id
  FROM
    matching
  WHERE
    has_opponent = 0
  GROUP BY
    match_id
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
) AS nop2
  ON m.match_id = nop2.match_id
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    match_id
  FROM
    matching
  WHERE
    has_opponent = 1
) AS samep2
  ON m.match_id = samep2.match_id
```

You could arguably leave off either the hasp2 or samep2 join and just assume that if the other two scenarios are not met, depends on how well you trust the data to know if that's a viable option.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the solution especially for mentioning about the trustworthy of data.

Answer (score 1):

The only tricky part is dealing with multiple players which is well-suited to using window functions and `row_number()`; Then it's just a case of aggregating these with a conditional case:

```
select match_Id, date, 
    Max(case when cnt=1
        then name 
    else
        case when rn=1 then name end
    end) first_opponent_name,

    Max(case when cnt=1 then
        case when has_opponent=1 then name else '' end
    else
        case when rn=2 then name end
    end) second_opponent_name

from (
    select m.match_id, m.date, m.has_opponent, p.name, 
      Row_Number() over(partition by match_id order by player_id)rn, 
      Count(*) over (partition by match_id) cnt
    from matching m
    join players p on p.id=m.player_id
)x
group by match_id, date
```

See [working example Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=360c51cbec0380a116b1257a741e0356)

Comment: Nice solution, worth noting though that window functions are only in MySQL 8+ and MariaDB 10.2+

Comment: It's first time for me to know that there's such function exists.
Thank you!

Comment: I just wonder  why do we have to use aggregate function MAX() here? since it will return only single one value.

Comment: @samrith.v because the query is aggregating rows - where there are multiple players there are 2 rows returned that need to be collapsed into 1 row using `group by` - the case expression returns either the value we want or `null` and `max` aggregates these into 1 row discarding the `null`

Answer (score 1):

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT DISTINCT
                     match_id,
                     `date`,
                     MIN(player_id) OVER (PARTITION BY match_id) p1,
                     MAX(player_id) OVER (PARTITION BY match_id) p2,
                     has_opponent
              FROM matching )
SELECT match_id,
       `date`,
       p1.name first_opponent_name,
       CASE WHEN has_opponent OR (p1 != p2) THEN p2.name END second_opponent_name
FROM cte
JOIN players p1 ON cte.p1 = p1.id
JOIN players p2 ON cte.p2 = p2.id
ORDER BY 1
```

If CTE and window functions are not supported then

```sql
SELECT match_id,
       `date`,
       p1.name first_opponent_name,
       CASE WHEN has_opponent OR (p1 != p2) THEN p2.name END second_opponent_name
FROM ( SELECT match_id,
              `date`,
              MIN(player_id) p1,
              MAX(player_id) p2,
              has_opponent
       FROM matching
       GROUP BY match_id,
                `date`,
                has_opponent ) cte
JOIN players p1 ON cte.p1 = p1.id
JOIN players p2 ON cte.p2 = p2.id
ORDER BY 1
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&rdbms2=mysql_5.7&fiddle=4b947a2e7d31d50dfc1242b194b204fe

The query assumes that the same `match_id` strictly matches the same `date` and `match_id`.

Comment: Really appreciate that, brother!